# Rename directory using a variable

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a directory that contains thousands of sub-directories. Structure like this:

Dirs:

- 1
- 2
- 30
- 109

I want to rename all the directories by adding 10000 to their current name.
E.g.

Dirs:

- 10001
- 10002
- 10030
- 10109

I have written this script

```bsh
for f in *; do
    if [[ -d $f ]]; then
        echo $f
        newd='expr $f + 10000'
        echo $newd
        mv $f newd
    fi
done
```

from the 2 `echo`s, I can see 1 and 10001.
But the `mv` actually move all my directories into a new folder called newd.
I tried $newd, doesn't work as well.

What could be done to make this thing works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you do this?

```
for f in *; do
    if [[ -d $f ]]; then
        echo $f
        newd=`expr $f + 10000`
        echo $newd
        mv "$f" "$newd"
    fi
  done
```

That is, change the quote marks around `expr $f + 10000` to backticks so they're executed in place and the result is stored in the variable.  Also make sure to have the dollar sign on `$newd` on the `mv` line.

I'm not 100% sure of myself so make sure to backup before you try or try on some test files/dirs.

Edit: added double quotes to answer as they turned out to be required.

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention that I did use the ` symbol on line4. I change to ' because askubuntu use ` to represent code block and I can't seem to escape it. I used your suggested code, and no error is shown. But none of the directories is renamed.

Comment: I just posted an almost identical answer without realizing it was identical to this one. @Calvin This script works for me, make sure you're running it in `bash` (altough I guess some error should have come up): add the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and `chmod +x script.sh && ./script.sh` or simply run `bash script.sh`

Comment: Thanks thomasrutter & @kos. I manage to get it working by mv "$f" "$newd"  (By adding the double quotes.)

Comment: @Calvin Indeed. The problem didn't come up in my test, because I tried using directories named as your example. Of course you want the `""`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for f in *; do 
    if [[ -d $f ]] ; then 
        mv "$f"  $(($f + 1000))
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `rename`:

```
for f in *; do 
    [ -d "$f" ] && rename -n 's/$_/$_+1000/e' "$f"
done
```

If you want to rename every file or directory, just run:

```
rename -n 's/$_/$_+1000/e' *
```